# How to invalidate or refresh notification buttons

Tags: google-cast, google-cast-sdk

Is there any way to change the notification buttons depending on the type of content being casted. Skip button makes sense only for on demand content and not for live content.

In current API, CastOptionsProvider is used only once when the cast content is initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible right now but could be supported in a new version.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139964273